# Spring testing and JsonPath probblem

Tags: spring-mvc, jsonpath

I am having an issue with testing and json path

I am just trying to perform a simple test and check the value of id:

```
mockMvc.perform(get("/applications/")).andExpect(status().isOk())
       .andDo(print())
       .andExpect(content().contentType(TestUtils.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8))
       .andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(4)))
       .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id",is(1)));
```

But I get an error like the following.  Seems like my code should be checking the id value. Am I not being specific enough since there are multiple items in the returned JSON?  Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
     Content type = application/json;charset=UTF-8
             Body = [{"id":1,"name":"test2"},{"id":2,"name":"test2"}]
   Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.id", exception: Expected to find an object with property ['id'] in path $ but found 'net.minidev.json.JSONArray'. This is not a json object according to the JsonProvider: 'com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.JsonSmartJsonProvider'.
    at org.springframework.test.util.JsonPathExpectationsHelper.evaluateJsonPath(JsonPathExpectationsHelper.java:258)
    at ...
```

Comment: Also you can always open any JSON path evaluator online tool, insert your JSON and test directly how the field is retrieved with your jsonPath query.

Answer (score 12):

I figured out the answer5 minutes after posting. Needed to go deeper into the array. This works:

```
.andExpect(jsonPath("$.[0].id",is(1)));
```

Comment: It didnt work for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47818094/json-keys-having-space

Answer (score 8):

Your JsonPath expression is wrong, because your response in the body is an array.
According to the [JsonPath Specification](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/), this syntaxes are all correct:

```
"$[0][id]"
"$.[0].[id]"
"$[0].id"
"$.0.id"
```

This [useful page](http://jsonpath.com/) can also help you to find out the jsonpath expression for your tests.

Comment: It didnt work for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47818094/json-keys-having-space